# Channel Form Custom Field

Tags: channel-form

Is there anyway to add a file custom fieldtype in a channel:form tag like so:

```
input type="file" name="photo_banner" value="{banner_photo}"
```

Instead of:
{field:banner_photo}

I can get the latter to work, but not the former.

Thanks,

Fabian

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use {field:banner_photo} if it works?

Comment: I want to leverage a jquery upload plugin that provides some neat interface features, but the plugin requires some extra data attributes in the file field.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to achieve this by using the {field:custom_field} method, then inspecting the DOM and copying the div.file_field element, and adding it directly to my template. I also had to copy over the safecracker script tag that the {field:custom_field} tag generated.